# Rename files in subfolders

Tags: powershell, rename

I am trying to rename files in subfolders in a certain pattern, but I am stuck.

The situation is as follows: I have multiple folders which are sometimes named as the target filename depending on the length, but the name does not really matter.

In each folder are always 2 files: the Target-File with a random name and the correct extension, and the Source-File which is always the correct BaseName with a txt-extension.

For example:

```
Folder1\7393028473.docx
Folder1\January.txt
Folder2\9373930843.pdf
Folder2\February.txt
```

My goal is to rename every not-txt-file with the Basename of the txt-file. Executed, it should be like:

```
Folder1\January.docx
Folder1\January.txt
Folder2\February.pdf
Folder2\February.txt
```

With gci I was able to create both lists but didn't find a good way for the renaming.

```
$SourceName = gci -File -Recurse | Where {$_.Extension -ne ".txt"}
$TargetName = gci -File -Recurse | Where {$_.Extension -eq ".txt"}
```

I did also try to use gci for renaming, but was not able to tell it to use the newname based on the txt-file:

```
gci -File -Recurse | Where {$_.Extension -ne ".txt"} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.extension -eq ".txt"}
```

This only renamed the .docx-file to "FALSE" because the filename already exists.

What I did not try (but would be ok) is to not only rename the file, but also move it to the parent directory.

Comment: what happens if by chance there is more than 1 file with a different extension and they happen to have the same different extension

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it but it would fail as soon as there are 2 or more files with a different extension than `.txt` but having the same extension. It would also fail as soon as one folder has more than one `.txt` file.

```bash
# Get all folders under 'TargetDirectory'
Get-ChildItem TargetDirectory -Directory -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    # For each sub-folder, get their files
    $childs = $_.EnumerateFiles()
    # Filter and split the child files by their extension
    $txt, $notTxt = $childs.Where({ $_.Extension -eq '.txt' }, 'Split')
    # Use the BaseName of the '.txt' File but the Extension of
    # the file being renamed
    $notTxt | Rename-Item -NewName { $txt.BaseName + $_.Extension }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply and sorry for my late reply.
I tried your code but its not working correctly:
The NewName is created correctly, but the problem is the rename-function or rather the notTxt list because it only contains the item itself but not hte full path.
When I copy the file which should be renamed into the parent-directory your code does work in the file in the parent-directory.

There was another answer which apperntly was deleted but did work.
I also tried a foreach-loop in one of my tries but didn't get the NewName to work.
I don't know why, but I didn't consider creating the NewName with a variable, which was done in the deleted answer:

```
$folders = gci -Directory -Recurse
foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    $targetFile = gci $folder | Where {$_.Extension -ne ".txt"}
    $sourceFile = gci $folder | Where {$_.Extension -eq ".txt"}
    $newName = $sourceFile.BaseName + $targetFile.Extension
    Rename-Item $targetFile.FullName $newName
}
```

Of course you can try and get your code to work, but I can make do with this code.
Thank you very much for your help.